# Innermost click event called inside the Event listener is not being fired

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, click

EDIT with reproducible example, and following T.J. Crowder suggestion below (tnx)

I need a button to be automatically clicked when I click on an element with class 'menu'.

I can get the element on the DOM, length is ok, and when I put a debug watch on it2, all properties seem ok. However, in the application I'm applying it the click event is not fired. In that case the 'menu' items have also their own click event listeners doing their stuff, which might hold the reason. Anyone have an idea why may not be working?

I have a similar working example that I tried, and apparently works

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('.menu').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
         if (document.querySelectorAll('.savebtn').length>0){
         
              var all = document.querySelectorAll('.savebtn');
              var it2=all[0];
              it2.click();       
    
          }
      })
    })
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=1" target="_blank" class="menu" > link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=2"  target="_blank" class="menu"> link 2</a></li>
</ul>



<form action="http://www.google.com/search"  target="_blank">
  
  <input type="text" name ="q">
  <input type="submit" class = "savebtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

any help ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm we probably can't help you without more context, ideally an [mre].

Comment: Side note: Be sure to declare your variables. The above looks a **lot** like it's creating implicit globals (`all`, `it2`).

Comment: It might also help to clarify whether the code you're posting is the code with the problem, because the line above the code sections makes it sound like the code posted is the similar working example that apparently works.